# How to turn off all sounds and vibration via Android API

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app, and I'm trying to disable all sounds and vibration of the device when the app starts.

I'm a newbie so I cannot find how to do that.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks! :) I reply myself to complete the answer:

```
AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Comment: This works, but it shuts off the device sounds for all apps.  It also shuts off TalkBack.  Just an FYI.

Comment: @mtb `F` ain't vowel BTW ;)

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustVolume%28int,%20int%29) here and take a look at `public void setRingerMode (int ringerMode)` with the `RINGER_MODE_SILENT` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add to the manifest file, permission to change the audio settings. To be able to set ringer mode to silent, you must ask permission to access notification policy

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

and then in a `onClick` event (below is for a `textView`) you can toggle the sound settings one by one:

```
    // attach an OnClickListener
    audioToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // your click actions go here
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Check if the notification policy access has been granted for the app.
            if (!notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
            ToggleDoNotDisturb(notificationManager);
            }
    });  


  private void ToggleDoNotDisturb(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    if (notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL) {
        notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
        audioToggle.setText(R.string.fa_volume_mute);
    } else {
        notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
        audioToggle.setText(R.string.fa_volume_up);
    }
}
```

also you need to check permissions

```
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 // Check if the notification policy access has been granted for the app.
 if (!mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```