# How to turn off all sounds on Android

Tags: android

I'm new developing on Android. I'm have a view with a ToggleButton on it that when pushed will turn off all sound until the ToggleButton is pushed again.

Currently, I have this code. I can see the logging events happening, but the sound is not turning off. Can anyone provide some insight?

```
 public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    Log.i("onToggleClicked", "ToggleClick Event Started");
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        Log.i("onToggleIsChecked", "ToggleClick Is On");
        //turn off sound, disable notifications
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
        Log.i("STREAM_SYSTEM", "Set to true");
        //notifications
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
        Log.i("STREAM_NOTIFICATION", "Set to true");
        //alarm
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
        Log.i("STREAM_ALARM", "Set to true");
        //ringer
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
        Log.i("STREAM_RING", "Set to true");
        //media
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        Log.i("STREAM_MUSIC", "Set to true");

    } else {
        Log.i("onToggleIsChecked", "ToggleClick Is Off");
        // turn on sound, enable notifications
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
        Log.i("STREAM_SYSTEM", "Set to False");
        //notifications
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
        Log.i("STREAM_NOTIFICATION", "Set to False");
        //alarm
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
        Log.i("STREAM_ALARM", "Set to False");
        //ringer
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        Log.i("STREAM_RING", "Set to False");
        //media
        amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        Log.i("STREAM_MUSIC", "Set to False");
    }
    Log.i("onToggleClicked", "ToggleClick Event Ended");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: chk this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558650/how-to-set-volume-for-text-to-speech-speak-method

Comment: But how can i disable all sounds so that even other application can't change any volume. i mean how to completely disable AudioManager from other application. @SunnyKumarAditya

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing the event to a listener

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //create the toggle button ref and instantiate
    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.tglSetStatus);
    tb.setTextOff(getString(R.string.available_status));
    tb.setTextOn(getString(R.string.driving_status));
    //default to being available
    tb.setChecked(false);
    // attach an OnClickListener
    tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // your click actions go here
            Log.i("onToggleClicked", "ToggleClick Event Started");
            //an AudioManager object, to change the volume settings  
            AudioManager amanager; 
            amanager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

            // Is the toggle on?
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton)v).isChecked();

            if (on) {
                Log.i("onToggleIsChecked", "ToggleClick Is On");
                //turn ringer silent
                amanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                Log.i("RINGER_MODE_SILENT", "Set to true");

                //turn off sound, disable notifications
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
                Log.i("STREAM_SYSTEM", "Set to true");
                //notifications
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
                Log.i("STREAM_NOTIFICATION", "Set to true");
                //alarm
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
                Log.i("STREAM_ALARM", "Set to true");
                //ringer
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
                Log.i("STREAM_RING", "Set to true");
                //media
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                Log.i("STREAM_MUSIC", "Set to true");

            } else {
                Log.i("onToggleIsChecked", "ToggleClick Is Off");

                //turn ringer silent
                amanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                Log.i(".RINGER_MODE_NORMAL", "Set to true");

                // turn on sound, enable notifications
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
                Log.i("STREAM_SYSTEM", "Set to False");
                //notifications
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
                Log.i("STREAM_NOTIFICATION", "Set to False");
                //alarm
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
                Log.i("STREAM_ALARM", "Set to False");
                //ringer
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
                Log.i("STREAM_RING", "Set to False");
                //media
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
                Log.i("STREAM_MUSIC", "Set to False");
            }
            Log.i("onToggleClicked", "ToggleClick Event Ended");
        }
    });
```

I found input by looking at these questions: [How to turn off all sounds and vibration via Android API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848146/how-to-turn-off-all-sounds-and-vibration-via-android-api)
and this one: [attach onClickListener to ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141531/attach-onclicklistener-to-togglebutton)

Comment: But how can i disable all sounds so that even other application can't change any volume. i mean how to completely disable AudioManager from other application? @briandus